# probably moronic js syntax error. Object is null

Tags: javascript, html, null, addeventlistener

```
var fbToggle = document.getElementById("fbToggle");
```

and later in the script

```
fbToggle.addEventListener("click", toggle("fbContainer"));
```

Console tells me that `fbToggle` is `NULL`

This is in the document though.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="fbToggle">
```

I wasnt using `eventListener` before, so maybe there is a special order of declaration i'm missing ?

EDIT :

entire js :

```
function toggle(target) {
var obj = document.getElementById(target);
display = obj.style.display;
if (display == "none") {display = "block"}
else {display = "none"}
}

function init() {
var fbToggle = document.getElementById("fbToggle");
var twitToggle = document.getElementById("twitToggle");
var pinToggle = document.getElementById("pinToggle");   
console.log(fbToggle); // NULL
fbToggle.addEventListener("click", toggle("fbContainer"));
twitToggle.addEventListener("click", toggle("twitContainer"));
pinToggle.addEventListener("click", toggle("pinContainer"));
}

window.onload = init();
```

HTML is way too long.but JS is in head, called from external file. Also i'm not in quirk mode.

Comment: This should work. Is by any chance `var fbToggle = document.getElementById("fbToggle");` called before the element is rendered? For example, it is before the element in html code?

Comment: Also, since it's "later in the script", can you confirm that the place where you invoke `fbToggle.addEventListener` still has `fbToggle` in scope? Can you `console.log(fbToggle)` immediately after you do `document.getElementById` to confirm it is not `null` there, and is at the other place?

Comment: Maybe you execute the line `var fbToggle =` before that element is in DOM (for example `<script>` is in `<head>`, but the element in `<body>`, so it isn't there when script is executed).

Comment: Well yes , it is in head , but not inline , i invoke it onload. Tried the console,null right away. To clearify "later in script" means there are two exactly same declarations with different values, so it is two lines afterwards. Is it possible element that has `display:none` is not in the DOM ?

Comment: Can you show more of your HTML and JavaScript outline? There might be the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, putting brackets after a function name causes it to be called. If you want to reference a function without calling it you must not put brackets after the name:

```
window.onload = init(); // this calls init() immediately
window.onload = init; // this correctly stores init in window.onload
```

The same applies to `toggle()`. If you need to pre-specify some of the arguments you can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
fbToggle.addEventListener("click", function() { toggle("fbContainer"); });
```

or you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
fbToggle.addEventListener("click", toggle.bind(null, "fbContainer"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where "later in the script" is. If it is in different scope definitely it is not going to work. Suggesting you to keep everything in a global object if possible so that you can access from different places in the script.

```
window.globals = {};
window.globals.fbToggle = document.getElementById("fbToggle");


window.globals.fbToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle("fbContainer")
});

function toggle(container) {
    alert(container);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ST938/

Another point is `addEventListener` expects a function or function idenitifier, NOT a function call.

```
addEventListener("click", toggle("fbContainer"));  // wrong
addEventListener("click", toggle);  // correct
```

So if you want to pass a parameter

```
window.globals.fbToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle("fbContainer")
});

function toggle(container) {
    alert(container);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer still apply when i edited my question ? I mean the scope part , i will redo the `eventListener`